# Two orderBy sorting in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sorting

If index code is as below, how to modify to get the correct sorting result?

Is it view rendering question instead of sorting in back-end?

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
           ->where('user_id', $user_id)
           ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
           ->orwhere(function ($query) use ($user_id) {
               $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                   ->whereMonth('deleted_at', date('m'));
           })
           ->orderBy('is_running', 1)
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Expecting result is

1. `is_running` must on top
2. the other records position after top line.

   ```
    created_at | is_running
    12.Feb.19  |    1
    13.Feb.19  |    0
    11.feb.19  |    0
    10.feb.19  |    0
    09.feb.19  |    0
        *      |    0
        *      |    0
   ```

Answer (score 0):

A very little change is needed.

The orderBy expects the column to order and the direct. So change `->orderBy('is_running', 1)` to `->orderBy('is_running', desc)`. This will put the largest to the top.

```
$jobs = DB::table('jobs')
           ->where('user_id', $user_id)
           ->whereMonth('created_at', date('m'))
           ->orwhere(function ($query) use ($user_id) {
               $query->where('user_id', $user_id)
                   ->whereMonth('deleted_at', date('m'));
           })
           ->orderBy('is_running', desc)
           ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
```

Comment: Can you show what you are currently getting and your front-end code please?

Comment: front-end code is not included special query statements, it just using `@foreach($jobs as $job)` as just to render it. thx ;)

Comment: I suspect that created_at is not using the standard format, and that's why it is acting weird ... it should be timestamp